# How add icon and Splash Screen in Phonegap Project?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am currently working on developing a cross platform mobile application and look for a solution to create Icon of app and adding of splash screen for Apps, say for example a Icon of app and splash screen.

Comment: read [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html)

Answer (score 0):

well, so you might be developing using html.,

You may use some JavaScript pre-loaders on your home page of your application, they will work exactly as Splash screen, but make sure to disable it after first application launch, or you may see them each time you navigate to homepage.

Otherwise you can use an extra html page for splash screen itself, and set it to redirect automatically to your home page after 3 or 5 seconds

I just found some Docs, may help you : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/config_ref/images.html